# Branch.io: Is there a way to specify which page a branch banner can appear on in a single page app?

Tags: branch.io

I am using a branch.io banner via the branch.io SDK on a site that is a single page app.
Branch has a feature where it lets you specify the urls where the banner will appear.

The problem is because my site is a single page app, branch appears to fail to recognize page changes, and which page is actually being viewed.

is there any way to configure branch smart banners to slow on specific pages when using it on a single page app, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

Jackie from Branch here.
Here's how we support single page web apps.

- Close the current Journey: https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/journeys/#closing-a-journey-programmatically
- Trigger to show the Journey: https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/journeys/#trigger-a-journey-to-show-by-firing-an-event
- Set deep link data(https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/journeys/#deep-linking-from-the-banner-or-interstitial) - this is only required if custom key-value pairs are used. With Canonical URL, Branch handles this at its end.

As a point of reference, feel free to take a look at our example single app, using the above features: https://mikekwon36.github.io/owners_testpage

Hope this helps!